# Regular Expression for first bracket checking

Tags: python, regex

I am working with regular expression in python, need an expression which will check for bracket "()" and after the characters.That means it will catch only "test()abc" not "test()".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple: `\w+\(\)\w+`

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check if the brackets are there, you can use `'\w\(\)\w'` as Chris Morgan said.

If you want to get a match just on the () (for example, for re.sub), you can either use non-consuming groups, or use word boundaries.

1. `'(?<=\w)\(\)(?=\w)'` will match just the () but only if it is preceded and followed by a alphanum.
2. `'\b\(\)\b'` will match just the `()` but only if it preceded and followed by a word boundary (since both `(` and `)` would break up the word). Note that if you had to match alphanumeric characters in the middle of a word, you'd have to use `\B` instead. For example, `'\Babc\B'`.

Comment: Thanks for your detail mention.It will help me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this one and it worked fine for me.

```
/([\()\\]+)/
```